# JGroups not finding or loading main class

Tags: java, classpath, jgroups

So I'm currently working through the official JGroups tutorial [here](http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial/index.html.)

I compile the class, specifying the correct JGroups class path, however when I run the `SimpleChat`, I get the following error message.

```
User@0001-Macbook:~/Desktop/JGroupsTutorial/src$ javac -cp jgroups-3.4.0.Final-2.jar SimpleChat.java
User@0001-Macbook:~/Desktop/JGroupsTutorial/src$ ls
SimpleChat.class           SimpleChat.java            jgroups-3.4.0.Final-2.jar
User@0001-Macbook:~/Desktop/JGroupsTutorial/src$ java -cp jgroups-3.4.0.Final-2.jar SimpleChat
Error: Could not find or load main class SimpleChat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the location of your .class file to your classpath.

For Mac/Linux:

```
java -cp .:jgroups-3.4.0.Final-2.jar SimpleChat
```

For Windows:

```
java -cp ".;jgroups-3.4.0.Final-2.jar" SimpleChat
```